# Mysql Xtradb build indexes by sort instead of via insertion

Tags: mysql, io, innodb, xtradb

[This post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/12/09/thinking-about-running-optimize-on-your-innodb-table-stop/) says:

> If you’re running Innodb Plugin on Percona Server with XtraDB you get
>   benefit of a great new feature – ability to build indexes by sort
>   instead of via insertion

However I could not find any info on this. I'd like to have an ability to reorganize how a table is laid out physically, similar to Postgre CLUSTER command, or MyISAM "alter table ... order by". For example table "posts" has millions of rows in random insertion order, most queries use "where userid = " and I want the table to have rows belonging to one user physically separated nearby on disk, so that common queries require low IO. Is it possible with XtraDB?

Comment: No it's not possible. Innodb stores a table in a clustered index PRIMARY that is a B+tree with a primary key field(s)  as a key.  If you have a query "where userid=?" then create a secondary index on userid.

Comment: @akuzminsky, yeah but with secondary index on userid, there may be hundreds of io operations for a single query instead of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Clarification concerning the blog post

The feature you are basically looking at is [`fast index creation`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-create-index.html). This features speeds up the **creation of secondary indexes** to InnoDB tables, but it is only used in very specific cases. For example the feature is not used while `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, which can therefore be dramatically speed up by dropping the indexes first, then run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and then recreate the indexes with `fast index creation` (about this was [the post you linked](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/12/09/thinking-about-running-optimize-on-your-innodb-table-stop/)).

Some kind of automation for the cases, which can be improved by using this feature manually like above, [was added to Percona Server](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/11/06/improved-innodb-fast-index-creation/) as a system variable named `expand_fast_index_creation`. If activated, the server should use fast index creation not only in the very specific cases, but in all cases it might help, such as `OPTIMIZE TABLE` — the problem mentioned in the linked blog article.

## Concerning your question

Your question was actually if it is possible to save InnoDB tables in a custom order to speed up specific kind of queries by exploiting locality on the disk.

This is not possible. InnoDB rows are saved in pages, based on the clustered index (which is essentially the primary key). The rows/pages might be in chaotic ordering, for which one can `OPTIMIZE TABLE` the InnoDB table. With this command the table is actually recreated in primary key order. This allows to gather primary key local rows on the same or neighboring pages.

That is all you can force InnoDB to do. You can read [the manual about clustered index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html), another page in the manual as a [definite answer that this is not possible ("ORDER BY does not make sense for InnoDB tables because InnoDB always orders table rows according to the clustered index.")](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) and [the same question on dba.stackexchange which answers might interest you](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5160/preordering-the-table-by-a-specified-column).